# JVM tuning for few and long GC runs

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection, jvm

My server application generates many die-young objects, so I assume the eden and survivor spaces are filled up pretty fast, which causes frequent GC runs.
My goal is to have few/long runs, say once a day, even if they require a couple seconds.

How would you tune the JVM for this target?
Which GC should I use? (**up to G1**).

Available heap space is around 4Gb (-Xmx4G)

Comment: are you talking about young or old gen collections? also, post GC logs and point out which parts are outside whatever you consider tolerable.

Comment: @the8472 I'm talking about frequent young generation collections.

Comment: The only way to reduce the long runs "full gc" is not to let let the memory build up. Running gc more frequent will keep the heaps small. Its the "pause-of-the-world" event (full gc) that you should be tuning. If your app is creating lots of new objects then you should be using parallelGC.

Answer (score 0):

In your case it is triggering for frequent minor gc's. You should use `"-XX:NewRatio=ratio"`

NewRatio this will decide the ratio between the old and young generatione.

For Example -XX:NewRatio=3 means that the ratio between the old and young generation is 1:3, the combined size of eden and the survivor spaces will be fourth of the heap.

Further you can finetune the Eden and Survivor spaces by using NewSize and MaxNewSize these parameters control the new generation’s minimum and maximum size.

By default NewRation=2 that means ratio between the old and young generation is 1:2.

You can read more details [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19900-01/819-4742/abeik/index.html)